# D3.js how to get multiple scales for data array?

Tags: d3.js

If I have 3 similar set of data, and I want for each data set have distinct scales, not axis just scales, x and y. How I should create it in d3.js paradigm?

```
var test_data = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

var arrays_groups = d3_main_chart
    .slectAll('.array_groups')
        .data(test_data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'array_group');

var group_pints = arrays_groups
    .selectAll('.group_rect')
    .data(function(d,i) {
        return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 5)
    .attr('cy', function(d){
        // y_scale for first array in test_data arrray
    })
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.... I don't believe your `.data()` selection is even valid. data needs an object, not a function. Perhaps you could explain more.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to use different scales, simply create and use different scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want something like this

```
var test_data = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

var scales = test_data.map(function(item){
    return d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([item[0], item.slice(-1)[0]])
        .range([0, 100]);
})

var arrays_groups = d3_main_chart
    .selectAll('.array_groups')
        .data(test_data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'array_group');

var group_points = arrays_groups
    .selectAll('.group_rect')
    .data(function(d,i) {
        return d.map(function(item) {
            return [item, i];
        })
    })
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 5)
    .attr('cy', function(d){
        var selected_scale = scales[d[1]];
        return selected_scale(d[0]);
    })
```

First step create array of scales.

Second step, when I pass data to circle I combine data and index of array from test_data, so in function where I calculate y coordinate I have index of scale.